# How to Permanently solve MySQL error 2002 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu

I have a problem on my cloud server with 2GB of RAM and 40GB Hard Disk that's hosting a Wordpress website that receives around 1000-2000 hits a day. My problem is that MySQL is always crashing and my only option is to reboot the server. I noticed that logs were not enabled so I enabled them and here is what i found:

```
150207 17:31:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.2G
InnoDB: mmap(1285636096 bytes) failed; errno 12
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150207 17:31:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150207 17:31:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150207 17:31:42 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150207 17:31:42 [ERROR] Aborting
150207 17:31:42 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I am guessing this has something to do with memory allocation or some settings in my my.cnf file. These are the contents:

```
[client]
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql
thread_cache_size              = 4
table_open_cache               = 800
table_cache                    = 800
key_buffer                     = 32M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size               = 64M
query_cache_limit              = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1G
innodb_io_capacity             = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads         = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 0
innodb_write_io_threads        = 64
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/ib_slow_log.log
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory problem, something very typical in a memory-bound system, and that can be confirmed on the line:

```
150207 17:31:42 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

As InnoDB cannot allocate memory for its buffer pool, it fails, and MySQL cannot start if the InnoDB engine fails (MySQL 5.5).

Nothing on your my.cnf seems out of the ordinary, but given that you only have 2GBs of ram, and if I understand it correctly, that is shared with the OS and a PHP/Wordpress installation, you have to be very conservative. MySQL is already taking 1.2 GB for the buffer pool, you should monitor the memory usage (`top`, `ps`) and making sure MySQL is the process to blame (compared to, for example, Apache). If it is, **reduce your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and/or some of the other buffers**, such as the key cache or the query cache. I would set the buffer pool to ~500MB for this non-dedicated server.

You seem to be running 5.5, for other folks running 5.6, one of the main causes I have seen in MySQL support regarding out of memory killings in small-memory systems is the extra static memory needed for the `performance_schema`. In those cases, I recommend disabling it or reducing `max_connections` to avoid too much overhead.

Comment: Thank you so much @jynus for your informative answer. I have used the htop command to check my memory usage and I figure out 2GB is too little for my server running MySQL, Varnish, Apache and more. I think the best solution would be to increase my RAM to at least 4GB? What do you think? And thanks again!

Comment: @realnsleo Reducing memory usage or increasing available memory depends on many factors, like the effectiveness of the buffer pool (`1 - innodb_buffer_pool_reads/innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests`, `1 - Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free/(Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free)`) or the cost of the extra memory, but yes, in general, that will solve the problem, too.

Comment: Wow @jynus Thanks again. I should definitely read more about innodb optimizations more specifically the buffer pool and query cache so that I can have a better idea on what to increase/decrease or modify, seeing as those are some of the major variables to look out for. Could you be having any good resources I can read from? Otherwise thank you for your answers and helpful explanations.

Comment: The reference manual is not a good tutorial, but you should have it handy (InnoDB section): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html Planet MySQL usually has lots of performance tips, specially from the Oracle and Percona engineers: http://planet.mysql.com This @realnsleo book is usually quiet praised: http://www.highperfmysql.com/ (Disclainer, I worked for Oracle and Percona) If you want to know about internals, Jeremy Cole has a series, but can be a bit hardcore for beginners: http://blog.jcole.us/innodb/

Comment: Thanks @jynus, I have been reading the resources you've referred me to and I've gotten quite some useful information. I've increased my RAM and so far everything seems to be moving smooth. Time will tell but I will go on and read more information and get in tune with the basics. Otherwise thank you for pointing me into the right direction. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is WP using MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?

If MyISAM, then set `innodb_buffer_pool_size=0`.  If InnoDB, decrease innodb_buffer_pool_size to, say, 300M and key_buffer = 10M.

`table_open_cache` and `table_cache` (they are the same thing) could be lowered to 300.

Turn off the query_cache -- `query_cache_type = 0` and `query_cache_size = 0`.

```
innodb_io_capacity             = 200
innodb_read_io_threads         = 4
innodb_write_io_threads        = 4
```

Yes, more RAM would be another solution (without changing any tunables).

2K hits per day -- MySQL is asleep.  2K per minute begins to get interesting; 2K per second gets exciting.